# Unable to get new line in a .txt with python running on Ubuntu server

Tags: python, ubuntu, newline, carriage-return

I have a server running ubuntu 14.04. I transferred my code files from my local computer to the server, but I can't run my program correctly because of this part of my code:

```
for _ in range(5):
    some = "some"
    stuff = "stuff"
    list_1 = open('text.txt', 'a')
    list_1.write("%s %s \n" %(some, stuff))
    open('text.txt', 'a').close()
```

when I run it, the output is :

```
some stuffsome stuffsome stuffsome stuffsome stuff
```

I can't understand why because if I run it on my local computer the output is:

```
some stuff 
some stuff 
some stuff 
some stuff 
some stuff
```

that's really weird, any ideas?

Comment: What do you think `open('text.txt', 'a').close()` does?

Comment: Try This: [https://askubuntu.com/questions/915284/installing-python-3-6-1-on-ubuntu-14-04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/915284/installing-python-3-6-1-on-ubuntu-14-04) and now run the code.

Comment: @KenWhite Since Python, so to speak. Python chooses the right line break for the host OS.

Comment: Try This: https://askubuntu.com/questions/915284/installing-python-3-6-1-on-ubuntu-14-04 and now run the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works fine. The lines are terminated by a single `\n` (linefeed) character as used in Linux.

Probably you are viewing the content of `text.txt` in a Windows program, e.g. notepad? The expected line ending will be `\r\n` (carriage return, linefeed), but since the `\r` is missing notepad displays it as a single line.

You could check on your Ubuntu server. Log in to a terminal and enter:

```
$ cat text.txt
```

in which case you should see the contents as you expect.

Also, the final line `open('text.txt', 'a').close()` does absolutely nothing at all.